# C++ recursive algorithm for permutation

Tags: c++, string, recursion

The permute() function runs into an infinite loop and I can't seem to find why? 
i tried checking the function by removing the recursive call and it seems to be working fine. I also have the base case, so don't know where is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string smallString(string s, int k){    // computes a string removing the character at index k 
    int i,j;
    string res;
    for(i=0,j=0;j<s.length();i++,j++){
        if(i==k){j++;}
        res.push_back(s[j]);
    }
return res;
}
void permute(string s1, string s2, size_t len){
    if(len==1)
        {cout<<"length is equal to 1"<<(s1+s2)<<'\n'; return;} //base case
    else{
        for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
            string temp= s2.substr(i,1);
            s1.append(temp);
            string fin = smallString(s2,i);
            //cout<<temp<<'\t'<<s1<<'\t'<<fin<<'\t'<<fin.length()<<'\n';
            permute(s1,fin,fin.length());
            s1.erase((s1.length()-1));
            //cout<<"printing s1 : "<<s1<<'\n';
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    string s2="abc";
    string s1="";
    permute(s1,s2,s2.length());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may come as a shock, but you're calling `permute` recursively.

Comment: This may come as a shock, but no sane person will read unindented code like this.

Comment: IMO, generating permutation has fairly complex logic. Why don't you start debugging your own code with debugger, display text at each recursion, consider smaller input, you'll eventually figure the issue.

Comment: Have you considered `std::next_permutation` ?

Comment: @nightfold : edited the code with correct indentation

Comment: @Jarod42 I just wanted to do this as a task.

Comment: Add comments to your code so you can understand the flow of logic quickly when reading it. Also, it seems `smallString` could be replaced by calling the `erase` member function on `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in the "smallString" function. In that function, OutOfRange is used in s[j]. I put print like

```
for(i=0,j=0;j<s.length();i++,j++)
{
    if(i==k){j++;}
      cout<<"smallString:: s ::"<<s<<'\t'<<"k::"<<k<<'\n';
    res.push_back(s[j]); //Problem is here...
}
```

Now Output print is like

smallString:: s ::abc   k::0

smallString:: s ::abc   k::0

smallString:: s ::bc    k::0

smallString:: s ::bc    k::1

smallString:: s ::bc    k::1

smallString:: s ::b     k::0

smallString:: s ::b     k::1

smallString:: s ::b     k::1
.
.

So, At one point of time it comes as "s ::b     k::1" so you are selecting the character at the position 1 from the string "b".

String is basically an char array which start from 0 to (n-1). For string "b" only 0th position is having character 'b'. but we are accessing an non-existing position.

So it throws error and start looping continuously from here.

FIX FOR YOUR ISSUE:

```
for(i=0,j=0;j<s.length();i++,j++)
{
    if(i==k)
    {
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"smallString:: s ::"<<s<<'\t'<<"k::"<<k<<'\n';
        res.push_back(s[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sridhar thanks for the great help. But just one edit, I should skip the part if(i==k)
    {
        j++; // this part, because the 'for loop' does the part             for me. After the edit it runs fine, thanks.   
    }