# Algorithm for list of all possible set of sets of a set

Tags: algorithm, set

I'm having a hard time coming up with an algorithm for generating a list of all possible sets of sets of a set.  By that I mean, given a set S I would like to know all possible sets containing sets of the set S.  I probably didn't describe it too well so I'll give an example that will hopefully get the point across.

If S = `{1, 2, 3}`

I'm looking for:

> {{1, 2, 3}}
>
> {{1, 2}, {3}}
>
> {{1, 3}, {2}}
>
> {{2, 3}, {1}}
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3}}

While tedious I can generate these by hand but I'm having a hard time coming up with an algorithm I can put to code.

Comment: try searching for "set partitions", that's what you're after here

Comment: May we know what have you tried or you just want SO to solve this for you?

Comment: this kind of sounds like a problem fit for dynamic programming algorithms

Comment: DP may help to count the number of partitions efficiently, but if the goal is to generate them it sounds like recursive problem

Comment: I first spent some time with pen and paper, scribbling the sets by hand.  The first implementation that came to mind was recursion but for some reason the solution didn't come to me.  I see the suggestion below and verified that it does solve the problem.  The only thing I can think of as to why I didn't solve it myself is 'brain fart'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it recursively, and I show you how to find answer for {1 , 2 , 3} from {1 , 2}.

For a set with n elements by solving problem  without n'th element like this :

```
{{1 , 2}}
{{1}, {2}}
```

and then consider every sets that you create for n-1 elements. and add n'th element to every elements of this sets once like this :

from `{{1 , 2}}` we have :

```
{{1 , 2} , {3}}
{{1 , 2 , 3}}
```

from `{{1}, {2}}` we have :

```
{{1, 3}, {2}}
{{1} ,{2, 3}}
{{1}, {2}, {3}}
```

As you can see now we solve the problem for 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I started with.  For some reason I didn't end up combining {3} to all sets from {1, 2}.  Not sure why.

Comment: @nickdu your welcome, if it is what your are looking for, please dont forget to mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive algorithm like the below post and concept is same. I had answer this one earlier.

[C++ recursive algorithm for permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584354/c-recursive-algorithm-for-permutation/26588353#26588353)

Answer (score 0):

I see here two independent tasks:

- Given an ordered set **S** of N elements produce all possible [Permutations](http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/_files/documents/book/node156.html)
- Given a number N produce all [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of N where a single partition defines how the **S** is split into subsets. Here is the [algorithm](http://jeromekelleher.net/partitions.php).

Then you need for each permutation apply each partition. This will produce all possible result sets **Q** but some of them are duplicate, for example {{1, 2}, {3}} and {{2, 1} {3}}. The next step is to get rid of duplicates. This is tricky a bit. The solution is below.

**UPDATE**

Lets define a result set **Q** is *unique* if it satisfies criteria as follows.

Define **Q** as an ordered set: {P1, P2, P3, ...} where Pi is also an ordered set of elements {Xi1, Xi2, ...}. Then **Q** is *unique* if:

- elements of each set Pi are arranged in ascending order (i.e. Xi1 <= Xi2 <= Xi3 ...)
- sets Pi are arranged in ascending order of their sizes (i.e. sizeof(P1) <= sizeof(P2) <= sizeof(P3) ...)
- sets Pi are arranged in ascending order of their *maximums* (i.e. maximum_of(P1) <= maximum_of(P2) <= maximum_of(P3) ...), where *maximum* of Pi is the greatest element of it.

Exampe:

{{1,2}, {3,4}, **{6,5}**, {7,8}} - not unique

{**{3,4}, {1,2}**, {5,6}, {7,8}} - not unique

{{1,3}, {2,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}} - unique

{**{1,2}, {3}**, {4}, {5,6}, {7,8}} - not unique

Comment: This will produce both {{1,2},{3}} and {{2,1},{3}} while they're the same in fact

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated my answer accordingly.